# ContentShape placement of button side effect for custom shape?

Tags: swiftui

I would like to create a button out of my custom shapes, but it seems the `contentShape` is not taking effect when applied to the shape itself.

[image]

It only works when I add the modifier to the whole button. This seems contradictory to samples and wondering if there are side effects with this, or is there a more supported way to create buttons out of custom shapes?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let shape = Triangle()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button {
                print("Tapped: \(Date.now.timeIntervalSince1970)")
            } label: {
                shape
                    .stroke(Color.red, lineWidth: 10)
                    .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
                    //.contentShape(shape) <-- does not work!
            }
            .contentShape(shape) // <-- works but awkward
        }
        .padding(32)
    }
}

struct Triangle: Shape {
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        var path = Path()
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: rect.minY))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.maxY))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.maxY))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: rect.minY))
        return path
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see anything "awkward" here... by default button hit-test area is rectangular independently of Label (which is just presented label, button does not care about it).

If `contentShape` at that level confuses you, it is possible to create a modified styles and use it, like

```
            Button {

               // ... other code

            }
            .buttonStyle(TriangleButtonStyle())

// ...

struct TriangleButtonStyle: PrimitiveButtonStyle {
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        Button(configuration)
            .contentShape(Triangle())
    }
}
```

or even make it generic on shape like `TriangleButtonStyle<S: Shape>` to allow any shape.

Tested with Xcode 13.4 / iOS 15.5

Comment: Thanks for the added voice of reason. It was just awkward that whenever I use `contentShape`, it always works when adding it to the view within the button, but it's not behaving consistent to that when using custom shapes. So makes me wonder, why ever apply it to the view within the button and just always do this on the button itself.

Comment: Strange, if I replace your custom shape with Circle() inside label it does not work as well. Anyway, IMO behavior of button is persistent, and actually button styles is the publicly allowed way to modify it.